# Working out length of side of triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I'm taking mooculus course from https://mooculus.osu.edu/exercises/linearTriangles1 and am given following problem :
[image]

What is the intuition of the hint : 'length of DA = abscissa of D minus abscissa of A = 0 + 9 = 9 ? I'm not sure how the abscissa relates ?

Comment: That's not a hint, that's a specification. And it's a darned confusing one at that, in my opinion. What they mean is that $\overline{DA}$ is the length of the line segment $DA$, and it has the value $9$.

Comment: No, I think the hint tries to tell that $\angle ADB $ is right, so the length of $\overline{DA}$ is nothing but the difference of the abscissae.

Comment: $DA=D_x-A_x=0-(-9)=9$

Comment: It seems that the coordinates of A, E, and C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments for question, have answered with :

[image]